# NodeJs Express API, trying to adding data/updating data to MongoDB but getting "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am trying to add a new collection, using the same ObjectId from the my users collection that was already created. But when I run the API, I get the following error `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authRoutes = require('./auth.routes');
const profileRoutes = require('./profile.routes');

const router = express.Router();

router.use('/auth', authRoutes);
router.use('/profile', profileRoutes);

module.exports = router;
```

profile.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const profileCtrl = require('../controllers/profile.controller');
const router = express.Router();

router
  .route('/')
  .post(profileCtrl.create)
  .put(profileCtrl.update)
  .get(profileCtrl.read)
  .delete(profileCtrl.remove);

module.exports = router;
```

BaseCrudController.js

```
class BaseCrudController {
  constructor(dataService, varName) {
    if (!dataService) {
      throw new Error('Data service not found', 500);
    }

    this.varName = varName;
    this.dataService = dataService;

    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  create(req, res, next) {
    return this.dataService
      .create(req.user, req.body)
      .then((item) => res.json(item))
      .catch(next);
  }

  update(req, res, next) {
    return this.dataService
      .update(req.user, req[this.varName], req.body)
      .then((item) => res.json(item))
      .catch(next);
  }
```

BaseCrudService.js

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const APIError = require('../utils/api-error');
const BaseService = require('./BaseService');

class BaseCrudService extends BaseService {
  constructor(
    modelName,
    safeFields = [],
    adminFields = [],
    userIdField = null,
    populatedFields = [],
    listPoluateField = ''
  ) {
    super();

    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.safeFields = [...safeFields];
    this.fields = [...safeFields];
    this.adminFields = [...adminFields];
    this.userIdField = userIdField;
    this.populatedFields = [...populatedFields];
    this.listPoluateField = listPoluateField;
    this.model = mongoose.model(this.modelName);

    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  _getFiedlNames(user) {
    //maybe checking roles later
    return [...this.safeFields];
  }

  create(user, data, extraData = {}) {
    const Model = this.model;
    const createData = {};
    const fields = this._getFiedlNames(user);

    if (this.userIdField) {
      createData[this.userIdField] = user._id;
    }

    const item = new Model(
      Object.assign(createData, _.pick(data, fields), extraData)
    );

    return item.save();
  }

  update(user, item, data) {
    const fields = this._getFiedlNames(user);
    const updateData = _.pick(data, fields);

    Object.assign(item, updateData);

    return item.save();
  }
```

profile.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const profileSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  contactEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isEnabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  about: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  portfolioUrl: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  jobTitle: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  resumeUrl: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

Then when I try to test this in Postman, I get the following stack `"TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined\n    at ProfileService.create (/Users/tj/aydensoft/upwork-ABDS/portfolios/portfolios/services/BaseCrudService.js:46:43)\n    at ProfileController.create (/Users/tj/aydensoft/upwork-ABDS/portfolios/portfolios/controllers/BaseCrudContoller.js:20:8)\n`
Also the users collection automatically gets the _id:ObjectId("someNumber") when a user is added.

I tried many different ways but it ends up adding a totally different `_id:ObjectId("someNumber")` instead of the one matching `_id:ObjectId("someNumber")` in the users collection.

Comment: conventionally you don't set the doc id manually, mongodb does that for you automatically. try to console.log users in the create() function in BaseCrudService.js. as it doesnt seem to get a proper value.

Comment: Yeah, console.log for user comes back undefined

Comment: check the argument you pass when call that function, and make sure you are passing a valid value, i assume check req.users, or when you construct the class and call this function